# How to display PHP code stored in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database with code in 1 of the fields

```
test test test <?php $_GET['location']; ?>  test test
```

I am accessing display file test.php?location=abc
and displaying that record from database in the following way

```
 This is my <?php echo $row_display_content['location']; ?>
```

And the only result I have got is

```
This is my
```

have no idea how to make it works, so dynamic values may be displayed inside the text from database

Comment: Databases are for data. Don't store code in them.

Comment: correct, but I would like to display dynamic data in some of the content stored inside database

Comment: Do your dynamic content display programmatically. How do you want php interpreter to understand this This is my <?php echo test test test <?php $_GET['location']; ?>  test test; ?>. That is exactly what you are doing

Comment: dynamic content it's a location passed via $_get

Comment: okay cool, so how do I do This is my <?php echo "test test test  $_GET['location'] test test"; ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `eval` function. Btw, this is a terrible approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Edit:

```
$code = 'test test test <?php $_GET[\'location\']; ?>  test test';

eval('?>'. $code);
```

Comment: tried this one already and doesnt work, once you use eval you have got error

Comment: Agreed to this completely. There is countless ways of avoiding using eval. And if you get errors, then there is errors in the eval code rather than anything else.

Comment: @user974435 Try... eval('?> your code <?php echo "blah"; ?>');

Comment: <?php echo  eval('?>  $row_display_content['location']; <?php echo "blah"; ?>');  ?>

Comment: Use the eval function. Btw, this is a terrible approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Edit:

$code = 'test test test <?php $_GET[\'location\']; ?>  test test';

eval('?>'. $code); doesnt work ;( same result

Comment: @user974435 See my example, the single quotes need to be escaped. Edit: The syntax error is somewhere else in your script.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo "This is my ". eval('?>' . $row_display_content[\'location\'] . '<?php ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [eval](http://php.net/manual/de/function.eval.php) and you shouldn't include the php tags in your database entry. Furthermore, you should ask yourself if you actually want to store this in your database.

Comment: doesn't work even once I removed <?php ?> tags form DB same error

Comment: this is how I used eval <?php echo  eval($row_display_content['location']); ?>